# Error connecting to BitTorrent tracker: Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker

Tags: python, http, python-asyncio, aiohttp, bittorrent

I am working on a BitTorrent client in Python using the asyncio and aiohttp libraries.

I've a `Tracker` class which handles the communication with the tracker and a `TrackerResponse` class which upon successful connection, processes the tracker response, extracting the essential information such as the interval, number of seeders, and leechers, etc.

I'm using the following method in the `Tracker` class to make an annouce call to the tracker:

```
async def connect(self, first: bool = None, uploaded: int = 0, downloaded: int = 0):
        params = {
            'info_hash': self.torrent.info_hash,
            'peer_id': self.peer_id,
            'port': 6889,
            'uploaded': uploaded,
            'downloaded': downloaded,
            'left': self.torrent.total_size - downloaded,
            'compact': 1}
        if first:
            params['event'] = 'started'

        url = self.torrent.announce + '?' + urlencode(params)
        logging.info('Connecting to tracker at: ' + url)

        async with self.http_client.get(url) as response:
            if not response.status == 200:
                raise ConnectionError('Unable to connect to tracker: status code {}'.format(response.status))
            data = await response.read()
            self.raise_for_error(data)
            return TrackerResponse(bencoding.Decoder(data).decode())
```

Whenever, I try to download a torrent file, I get the following error:

> ConnectionError: Unable to connect to tracker: d14:failure reason63:Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker.e

This is despite the HTTP status code being 200.

I'm trying to identify the source of this error. Could there be specific tracker-related issues or configurations that might be causing this error? Are there additional steps or considerations when handling trackers that might impose authorization restrictions?

I'll really appreciate your help if any.

Comment: Please include the full traceback, the error doesn't seem like it matches your code. If the last part of the error message is actually from the response, then I suggest you contact someone involved with the server you are connecting to, or otherwise figure out what details you need to be "authorized" (e.g. maybe they only allow certain user-agents in the headers?).

Comment: @SamBull I'm trying to understand how to figure out the details which I need to know for authorization purposes. At the moment, I have a few torrent files in my PC which I'm trying to download through the client. One file name is:
ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: Again, you need to figure that out with the server you are trying to connect to. You've not provided any details about this other than it being related to BitTorrent. If that is your issue, then very little in your question is relevant information. A quick search of your error messages finds several reports of the error message, which suggests it might be because the torrent you are trying to use is obsolete: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456578/ubuntu-22-04-2-requested-download-is-not-authorized-for-use-with-this-tracker

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error means the tracker is not an open tracker, i.e. it only accepts a set of whitelisted infohashes and yours isn't among them.

If the tracker has an associated indexing site you can check there which torrents they currently offer.

If the tracker comes from the torrent's metadata then it's perhaps outdated and you'll have to look for a newer version of the torrent.